# Invariant Violation: new NativeEventEmitter() requires a non-null argument using Bluetooth in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently developing a bare React Native app trying to set up a Bluetooth connection with a device. I am wanting to use the library called 'react-native-ble-plx'. I am trying to set up the code to attempt to connect to a device and show me that I have connected to it. I used some code from a website https://blog.bam.tech/developer-news/make-your-first-iot-react-native-application-with-the-bluetooth-low-energy to attempt to follow their pattern to reproduce it.

The general idea is to first make a page to connect to the devices when a button is clicked. This will cause a method to be called that grabs all of the Bluetooth connections available and puts them on the screen. However, to do this, we need to create a Bluetooth Manager, aka the BleManager. This is precisely where my issue lies. When I try to write the following line, I get the error mentioned in the title:
const manager = new BleManager();

I have imported the BleManager from the library and am assuming it has something to do with the constructor of the BleManager, but not exactly sure how.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if anyone will run into this issue, but I was attempting to still run in with Expo commands. I needed to run it specifically in iOS (npm run ios), which proved to be the way to fix it.